# How would I retrieve the 5 values of positivity from Stanford's Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm looking to pass a string to get parsed and return the number (1-5) with the highest rating.

For example, this would return 2:

[image: For example, this would return 2:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline with the [`sentiment` annotator](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/SentimentAnnotator.java#L71).

This annotator sets an annotation on every sentence called [`SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName.html). Simply retrieve this value: (untested example)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// read some text in the text variable
String text = ... // Add your text here!

// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

// run all Annotators on this text
pipeline.annotate(document);

// these are all the sentences in this document
// a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
  String sentimentLabel = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName.class);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble understanding the API. This helps a lot!